# Simple Limit of Exponents

Tags: limits, exponentiation

Let $c_{j}$ be a sequence of positive integers with $c_{j}\leq j$ such that $\lim_{j\rightarrow\infty}\frac{c_{j}}{j}=r\in\left[0,1\right]$, and let $a,b$
be positive reals, with $a<b$.

Is: $$\lim_{j\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{a^{c_{j}/j}}{b}\right)^{j}\overset{?}{=}\lim_{j\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{a^{r}}{b}\right)^{j}$$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Notice that 
$$
\left( \frac{a^{\frac{c_j}{j}}}{b}\right)^j = \Big( a^{\frac{c_j}{j}- r} \Big)^j \, \Big( \frac{a^r}{b}\Big)^j
$$
So, for any case where the second factor converges, you'd need the first factor to converge to $1$. I bet you can find some counter examples, particularly if you look for cases such as when $\frac{c_j}{j} - r \sim j^{-1/2}$ or similar.

Comment: This is why I disapproved of the person who edited my original post. My original post began with the sentence "I'm having a brain-fart". And that was (in my opinion) important, because it gave context. xD

This isn't a homework problem. It's just something that came up in my research, and I'm in *waaaay* too deep at the moment to easily transfer to thinking about something like this.

I just wanted to know if the above statement was true, and, if it wasn't, what the conditions would need to be for it to be true or false. 

Addendum: what if $a$ and $b$ are rationals?

Comment: @MCS Take any $b > 1$ and $r > 1$. Set $a = b^{1/r}$ and $c_j = jr + \sqrt{j}$.